# Rails: Generating CRUD methods, why redirect to object id specific index after update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following along a Lynda course to learn Rails essentials, and they do something interesting that I observed. Just curious, and wondering why you might do this.

```
def update
  @section = Section.find(params[:id])
  if @section.update_attributes(section_params)
    redirect_to(sections_path(@section))
  else
    render('edit')
end
```

In the above code snippet, they redirect to the index, but seemingly add a URL parameter, such that it's the index specific to the section object. However, in the index method they have you write, it doesn't specifically list anything to accept that, so I'm wondering how that might be integrated in future projects, or why they're subtly hinting towards viewers that they should do this as standard practice? Is it something to do with potentially accepting additional parameters in the index with CRUD methodology?

Thanks!

```
def index
  @sections = Section.sorted
end
```

Comment: Can you post the `routes.rb`? Also are you sure it is redirecting to `index` page?

Answer (score 0):

The code you have mentioned says that after updating the `section` record, you want to redirect to the view of **updated section**

If you write

```
redirect_to sections_path
```

then it will be redirected to `sections#index` route and path formed will be `/sections`

However if you pass the instance to section_path

```
redirect_to section_path(@section)
```

or

```
redirect_to @section
```

It will redirect to `sections#show` route and path formed will be `/sections/section_id` for example `/sections/1` where section_id is the id or primary key of the section you have updated/edited.

For more on routes,verbs and actions please refer [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions)